# How to remove Anydesk completely from my Mac after scammer tricked us into granting access

Tags: mac, anydesk

Wife had already downloaded Anydesk when I came in. Scammer was in our screen and we completed “refund” form before he said we’d have to get into bank account only on that machine in order to stop bill. I then shut down all windows that would close. Some Anydesk remains on the Mac. Can he still have control?  How do I fully remove the program when I don’t have a relationship with Anydesk?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Menu > About AnyDesk.
2. Hold the option/ALT key.
3. Click "Uninstall" on the top right corner of the window.
4. Delete the `~/.anydesk/` and `/etc/anydesk/` folders for standard AnyDesk clients.

Note (to the non-informed): `~` refers to `$HOME` which is a variable representing your user's local/home folder.  You can go ahead and use the tilde `~` as it is the same thing but should understand what it means.  For instance, if your user name was ***billyjoebobebedearl***, your user folder would be in `/Users/billyjoebobebedearl`  if you (while logged in) were to use a command like `ls ~` or `ls $HOME`, the shell would run `ls /Users/billyjoebobebedearl`

For more detailed instructions on uninstalling AnyDesk, please view [this page](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/anydesk-on-macos)

Make no mistake, AnyDesk is powering the scammer world.  Until they change this practice, please don't support them.

If you have problems after following my guidance, please post back to this same thread IN THE QUESTION, NOT IN COMMENTS.

To others:  Please don't try to inform me about the differences between ~ and $HOME.  I am well aware and such a discussion will not help the OP.